# Why my kafka cosumer group does not work?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

I'm using sarama-cluster (written by Golang kafka consumer client)

In broker, my topic's  partition offset was 11000 and my consumer group's partition offset was 10100.
Then I run my cluster-consumer, but nothing consume. (consume time was 1~2days later)

But when I produce message in the topic's partition, it consume! (In each partition)

A number of message is 901.
Why is it, that my consumer-cluster consume seems to activate when produce message?

My consumer setting was auto.offset.reset = lastest

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your offset reset settings. `auto.offset.reset = latest` means your consumer group should wait for the newest records. If you want to consume from the beginning, use `auto.offset.reset = earliest`.

The official Kafka documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html

Comment: But it means Consumer will start consuming at offset no 0 ???? right?
I wanna consume offset no.10101 (in my example case)

Comment: should I commit offset number?

Comment: I'm afraid it would be difficult to read from specific offset, I guess. Usually your consumer reads the data from the last _known_ offset. If offset is unknown, then the _auto.offset.reset_ policy kicks in.

Comment: maybe I need this document. https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html#impl_offsettracking